# Removing automatic device-type from a driver

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, android

I accidentally installed the type of driver for my HTC Evo, and now, I cannot get it to associate with anything but "libusb-win32 devices". Is there a way to reset the device type back to the default that it had before I went on this escapade?